# How to overload the << operator for a vector<int> in C++

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc, ld

I made the following minimal example for operator overloading in C++. I would like to print the vector as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const vector<int>& v) {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
                out << v[i] << " ";
        }
        return out;
}

int main(void)
{
        vector<int> i = {1, 2};
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

However if I compile this with gcc as `gcc test.cpp` using the following version.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1) 9.3.0
```

I get error messages all over the place which seem to reduce to the following.

```
undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
```

But for completeness sake here is the complete error message.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8gPHc3.o: in function `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8gPHc3.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8gPHc3.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x1aa): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8gPHc3.o: in function `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_S_check_init_len(unsigned long, std::allocator<int> const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE17_S_check_init_lenEmRKS0_[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE17_S_check_init_lenEmRKS0_]+0x5e): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8gPHc3.o: in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim]+0x1c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8gPHc3.o: in function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x2c): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x3c): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8gPHc3.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Use g++, not gcc.

Comment: Using g++ indeed works. Thanks

Comment: [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](//stackoverflow.com/q/172587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `g++` instead of `gcc` solves the problem.